# Number of subquery call

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

TableA, TableB, TableC are three Tables with number of rows |A|, |B| and |C| respectively. How often must each subquery run? Are the results of two queries equivalent? Need explanation

```
a) SELECT * FROM TableA a
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM TableB b -- Subquery 1
WHERE a.ID = b.ID AND EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM TableC c -- Subquery 2
WHERE b.ID = c.ID
)
)
b) SELECT * FROM TableA a
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM TableB b -- Subquery 1
WHERE a.ID = b.ID AND EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM TableC c -- Subquery 2
WHERE a.ID = c.ID
)
)
```

Comment: Depends on what referential and unique constraints have been defined. Note that any given subquery might not run at all, if the optimiser can infer that it is not required (e.g. due to suitable constraints on the tables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How often must each subquery run?

You are working with correlated subquery and so for every row of outer query the inner query will get evaluated.

> Are the results of two queries equivalent?

In your case yes, in first query you are checking

For `TableA` there is match in `TableB` and for `TableB` there is a match in `TableC`

Whereas in second query you are checking

For `TableA` there is match in `TableB` and in `TableC`